Diamonds on supercompact $\kappa$ after a $\kappa$-c.c. forcing
Let $\kappa$ be supercompact. Then the (supercompact) Laver diamond holds at $\kappa$: There is $f:\kappa\to V_\kappa$ such that for all $\lambda\geq \kappa$ and $x\in H(\lambda^+)$ there is $j:V\to M$ witnessing the $\lambda$-supercompactness of $\kappa$ and $j(f)(\kappa)=x$. This implies the usual diamond on $\kappa$.
Suppose $P$ is a $\kappa$-c.c. poset with $|P|\leq \kappa$. What can we say about the diamonds that hold at $\kappa$ in the generic extension?

Isn't diamond still true? Use the ground model diamond to define $\dot{X}\alpha$ where  $\dot{X}\alpha$ is a P-name of a subset of $\alpha$, such thing can be coded by a subset of $\alpha$. Then you guess all the names. Finally, $\kappa$-cc forcing doesn't change stationarity wrt $\kappa$.

Yes, I'm interested in if some stronger forms of diamond remains (as well as what stronger diamonds cannot be introduced by such forcings).

I have doubts,  such a forcing can even destroy supercompactess of the cardinal ( even it's inaccessibility), just add $\kappa$ Cohen reals. You need first preserve enough supercompactess, then under mild conditions, each embedding is an extension of ground model embedding and then usually one gets what you want.

Welcome to MO! Perhaps it would be not bad to take a look at https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168007211001886?via%3Dihub, in particular Theorem 6.11.

@MohammadGolshani I think adding $\kappa$ Cohen reals might preserve the strong tree property of $\kappa$; at least, the tree property of $\kappa$ is preserved. Could that say anything?

@Rahman.M Thanks! This is what I was looking for in another question.

If $\kappa$ is supercompact, you still have "generic" laver diamond in the extension, in the sense of Definition 7 (see also Lemma 12) of my paper on this topic.  Generic Laver diamond implies 2-cardinal diamonds, see section 3 of that paper.  And you don't need the cardinality restriction on the poset $P$.
More generally, if $\Diamond^{\text{Lav}}_\kappa(\Gamma)$ holds in the ground model (where $\Gamma \subseteq \wp_\kappa(V)$) and the poset $P$ is proper with respect to enough members of $\Gamma$, then $P$ should preserve Generic Laver Diamond.
